# Receiving error message when push heroku master

Tags: git, heroku

I have never used Heroku before, but I am now trying to add a repo from GitHub so that I can see my project on Heroku. I have followed the instructions here https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#deploy-the-app but I get an error message when I try to push it to Heroku.
[image: demonstration]

This is the error message I get. When I do clone I use the link to the repo that you get from GitHub. Could anyone think of what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The server hook is rejecting your code for one reason or another. Make sure you are complying with their development process.

Comment: I have followed it step by step. It works when I'm using their example but it doesn't work when I try to add my existing repo.

Comment: Might make it easier to see what is missing, here is the git repo https://github.com/NaomiLea/SoftwareTextil

Answer (score 1):

You have the error message in the output. Heroku wasn't able to recognize language for your application. It means that it can't choose the method for deployment automatically.

You can set buildpack manually as described in [documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#setting-a-buildpack-on-an-application). Make sure that application works fine on localhost before pushing to Heroku. Something may be missing and this might be the reason for the error.